# Error in RAKE keyword extraction in python

Tags: python, nlp

I am using RAKE as instructed in this [simple tutorial](https://www.airpair.com/nlp/keyword-extraction-tutorial) for keyword extraction from text.

However, I want to add a custom stopword file `stopwords.txt` (not the default one that is named as `SmartStoplist.txt`). My code is as follows.

```
stoppath = "stopwords.txt"
rake_object = rake.Rake(stoppath)

for text in documents_list:
    print(rake_object.run(text))
```

However, when I try to run this it gives an error saying;

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'SmartStoplist.txt'
```

They means their default stopword list, but I want to run it with my current stopword list that is named as `stopwords.txt`.

Please let me know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Within the RAKE-tutorial folder search for the file rake.py
In line 29, set

```
test = False
```

The problem is that test is set to true, and this makes many of their default functionalities work. By setting it to false you can resolve your issue.